# Update conditional attributes on Meteor user login/logout

Tags: javascript, html, templates, meteor

I'm using Meteor with Iron-router (if that's relevant). I've made some changes to accommodate the 0.8 update, and I'm still struggling with some things.

Instead of using conditional attributes inside a div in html, I'm using .rendered to set those attributes. But now, when a user logs in, I must either refresh the page or navigate away and back (I don't think the refresh is necessary) so elements behave correctly.

Does anyone know how I can make these attributes behave correctly based on whether a user is logged in or logged out, IMMEDIATELY WHEN THE USER LOGS IN OR OUT?

```
Template.pt_entry.rendered = function() {
  $('#signin').popover(),
  $('#reviewModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#review-text').focus();
  });
  if(Meteor.userId()){
    $('#signin').attr( 'data-toggle', 'modal' ),
    $('#signin').attr( 'data-target', '#reviewModal' )
  } else {
    $('#signin').attr( 'data-toggle', 'popover' ),
    $('#signin').attr( 'data-container', 'body' ),
    $('#signin').attr( 'data-content', 'you must sign in to review' ),
    $('#signin').attr( 'data-trigger', 'click' )
    //add some logic for displaying error template.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have different options:

If you are using iron-router you can generally show different templates in the same route. You can check if the user is logged in and based on this check you can switch between templates. You can maybe check it with a beforeHook:

```
beforeHooks =  {
  isLoggedIn: function() {
    if(!(Meteor.loggingIn() || Meteor.user())) {
      Router.go('landingPage');
      this.stop();
    }
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(beforeHooks.isLoggedIn);
```

Another option is to use the default {{currentUser}} helper

```
 {{#if currentUser}}
   <p>User is logged in</p>
 {{else}}
   <p>User is not logged in</p>
 {{/if}}
```

Maybe the reason why your code doesnt work could be the new blaze engine. The rendered-callback is just fired once [Blaze](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#rendered-callback-only-fires-once). Normally Meteor.userId() is a reactive datasource so your template gets rerendered but if the rendered callback is just fired once the changes dont get applied. Maybe these minds help you!

Comment: Thanks. I think you're on to something with the first method, but I'd have to do something like that for both logging in and out. Basically, it would send a user that's logging in or out to the page he's already on. I'll look into it. The second method you listed looks like a simple no-brainer and should work, but I'm getting an error. In fact, I have it working for showing the username vs. the login button. Nonetheless, I get "Unexpected Else" when I try changing these attributes that way. It must have to do with the content, but I don't know what to edit.

Comment: Ok, I got around the "unexpected else" error. I was trying to avoid repeating all the content inside the "<p>User is logged in</p>" by starting the "else" after "<p>," but that was apparently doesn't work. Now my only issue is that the popover doesn't work without reloading or navigating away and back. Still working on it.

Comment: Can you update your example? Maybe i can give another hint if i can see what your purpose is.

Comment: Your second suggestion works. It's just that Bootstrap popovers are really tricky. The whole point here was to display a popover that tells users they have to login before they can access the review form. It works on the initial render, but not after logging out. My navigation buttons are in a different template than the bootstrap popover, and I couldn't find a way to initialize a popover using elements outside the template that houses it. I tried everything (sessions, dependencies, helpers). I ended up just setting "location.reload();" to run when my logout button is clicked.